# Is it possible to control minimum finger distance to trigger touchpad events?

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, macbook-pro, synaptics

I'm using touchegg and synaptics, and I'm trying to configure synaptics 3-finger gesture sensitivity. Currently, 3-finger dragging is being triggered by accident, and I think if I could configure a minimum finger distance for triggering events it would solve the matter.

I say this because I've realized that 3-finger gestures are being triggered no matter how appart the touch points are.

I've already enabled PalmDetect, and tweaked a bit, which helped a lot avoiding random 2-finger scrolling, but didn't help for 3-finger.

#### EDIT

At the moment, as a way out, I had changed my 3-finger gestures to 4-finger ones so it gets harder to generate random effects.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `HorizHysteresis` and `VertHysteresis` of synclient. Here's what they do according to `man synaptics`.

```
Option "HorizHysteresis" "integer"
              The  minimum  horizontal  HW distance required to generate motion events. Can be specified as a
              percentage. Increase if noise motion is a problem for you. Zero is disabled.  Default: 0.5 per‐
              cent of the diagonal or (in case of evdev) the appropriate "fuzz" as advertised by the device.

       Option "VertHysteresis" "integer"
              The minimum vertical HW distance required to generate motion events. See HorizHysteresis.
```

Comment: I had changed these properties but got no effect.